# Create List using nintex workflow for O365

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, list, nintex

we have migrated SP2013 site to SPO but there is no action for create List in nintex for O365. is there any alternative way to achieve that functionality?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you purchase Nintex for Office 365 in your tenant? Where do you expect to have that functionality? Please, describe in more detail your question.

Comment: yes i already have nintex in my tenant with full subscription. But i am unable to create lists with Nintex workflow.